# Ignore background value

Tags: raster, nodata, copy

I'm using Copy Raster (Data Management) function. I need to ignore background values which are = 0 but keep all pixels =0 that are inside the raster.

background_value should do it, however it does not do anything. I found this explanation:

*For file-based rasters, Ignore Background Value must be set to the same value as NoData for the background value to be ignored. Enterprise and geodatabase rasters will work without this extra step.*

But when I set Nodata_value = 0 then I get rid not only of background values but all 0 values inside a raster. I'm not sure how this should help.
Code sample:

```
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(ras, final_data_downloads_dir + os.sep
                                    + output_file_name, background_value=0, 
                                    pixel_type='8_BIT_UNSIGNED')
```

Comment: If the nodata value is 0 and you also have pixel values of 0 within the image data then there's no way to tell them apart, unless you have a separate transparency/mask band.  In that case you might have to use something like https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html

Comment: It works when I save a raster in a geodatabase, but not when I want to save it as a tif file. When I put it in a geodatabasse, it distinguishes between 'zero' inside raster and 'zero' in the background. The problem is that when I try to copy it and save it as a tiff, it automatically brings back the background.